# ExceptionInInitializerError with From String.format

Tags: java, android, string, format

I have a strange behavoir with String.format in my android app, what I don`t unterstand ...

I tried to make some static defines in an interface. This also worked fine, but in some cases I get an Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32450): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(32450):    at de.mydomain._defines_database$query.<clinit>(_defines_database.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(32450):    at de.mydomain.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:116)
....
E/AndroidRuntime(32450): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: format == null
E/AndroidRuntime(32450):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1995)
E/AndroidRuntime(32450):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1973)
E/AndroidRuntime(32450):    at de.mydomain._defines_database$table_coloumn.<clinit>(_defines_database.java:204)
E/AndroidRuntime(32450):    ... 16 more
```

My code in _defines_database:

```
Line  17: public interface _defines_database
Line  18: {
Line  19:   public interface query
Line  20:   {
...
Line  61:     public final static String eOrder      = table_coloumn.eStatus+" DESC, ";
...
Line 160:     public final static String  person_sign= "SELECT sign_%2$s FROM %1$s WHERE id_%2$s = %3$s";
Line 161:     public final static String user_sign   = String.format(person_sign,"user", "usr","%s"); 
Line 162:
Line 163:   }
...
...
Line 178:   public interface table_coloumn
Line 179:   { 
...
Line 183:     public final static String eStatus = "(CASE"
Line 184:                                        + "  WHEN `end_time` IS NOT NULL THEN '"+ Status.STOPPED.ordinal() +"'\n"
Line 185:                                        + "  WHEN `start_time`  IS NOT NULL THEN '"+ Status.STARTED.ordinal() +"'\n"
Line 186:                                        + "  ELSE '"+ Status.PLANNED.ordinal() +"'\n "
Line 187:                                        + "END)";
...
Line 204:     public final static String userTour = "name_tour || ' (' || ("+ String.format(query.user_sign,"user_tour")+ ")  || ')'";
...
Line 304:   }
Line 305: }
```

So what i don not understand: 1. the Exceptions is thrown by Line 61, but the cause is line 204 with reason the string format would be null.

But all variables come from static final String, so they never should be changed.
So the "format" parameter in Line 204 only could be NULL is the String.format in Line 161 would return a NULL-Value.

But as I understand the documentation String.format should NEVER return NULL.

And the second thing I`dont unterstand... My definition in Line 61 has nothing to do with Line 204, so how can Line 204 be the cause of this Exception ?

I found a related topic about this Exceptiontype, but it was not helpful for my problem.
@see: [ExceptionInInitializerError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901963/exceptionininitializererror)

**UPDATE:** When I change "user_sign" (in Line 161) to a static String without String.format() the error seems not to occour.
Maybe String.format() does not like that "%s" is inserted as one of the arguments ??

Comment: This also worked fine, but in some `cases` I get an Exception. In which cases?

Comment: I could not reconstruct this situations, but I the Exception was triggered after i returned to my app after it was in background a while.

I know that android cleares all variables when memory gehts low, but static final interface konstands should be restored automatically.

The error is thrown because somethings goes wrong on this intialistion steps.

Comment: Are you sure there were no other exception other then this?

Comment: Yes I am, its only this one exception, with an other exception as cause 
I have a textlogging of Exceptions and I also watched LogCat.

(See Loginfos in my post)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `table_coloumn.eStatus` is null. I don't know why the trace is on a different line though, but if you initialise `table_coloumn.eStatus` to a proper value it should start working.

And don't ask me why it works if you set `user_sign` directly with a String too. I don't have an answer to that too. Probably Magic...:P

Comment: eStatus is not Null, I yust forgot to post Lines 183-187 (now you can see these lines)